# Scala PlayFramework how can I inject repository method inside function

Tags: scala, playframework, dependency-injection, playframework-2.3

I am using the play framework version 2.49, I am trying to do a dependency injection and it is my first time doing this. I have 3 Folders Interface : Repository : Controllers. The interface lays out abstract methods that I implement inside a repository folder then inject into a controller action. I am only lost when it comes to the controller action. Here is a sample code of mines

**Interface**

```
package Interface


abstract class Iprofiles {
  def edit_profile
  def view_profile
  def forgot_password

}
```

**Repository**

```
package Repository

import Interface.Iprofiles
import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._

class ProfileRepository extends Iprofiles  {
  val db= Database.forConfig("database")

// These 3 methods will have Database logic soon
  def edit_profile: Unit
  def view_profile: Unit

  def forgot_password: Unit 
}
```

**Controller**

```
package controllers

import play.api.data.Form
import play.api.data.Forms._
class Relations extends Controller {


  def MyAction() = Action {
 // How can I inject edit_profile in the repository folder here
Ok()

}



}
```

My Repository methods are empty right now but I will have Data logic in them soon. In My controller **MyAction()** method for example how can I do a DI and include **edit_profile** from the repository folder ? I have been searching for how to get this done but nothing has worked

Comment: I have been looking at DI in Play (mostly using Guice) for couple last days, and my understanding is, that the recommended way is by injecting dependencies through constructors, not into methods. Would be that acceptable for you?

Answer (score 0):

Dependency Injection on the JVM is currently only about injecting object references, not method references. That is, in a class you declare a dependency to a type (typically an interface) and define the mapping from this (interface) type to an implementation (type) in the injector configuration.
During injection -typically during object construction - you get a reference to an object of the implementation type injected.

Then you can call all methods on that injected object.

So you need an attribute taking the reference and this is typically filled via a constructor parameter.